# shaded the feasible area

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have plot the constraints using R using ggplot. I wanted to shade the feasible area(which can be seen as the black line). I tried using the geom_abline but no luck generated the plot. here is the code

```
library(ggplot2)
plot_df = data.frame(Budget = c(0, 200))

ggplot(plot_df, aes(x = Budget)) + 
  stat_function(fun = \(x) {(100 - 0.20*x)/0.70}, aes(color = "line constraint1")) + 
  stat_function(fun = \(x) {(200 - x) }, aes(color = "line constraint2")) +
  labs(y = "Space")+ ggtitle("Plot kale vs Parsnips Growing")
```

figure is below where I wanted to shade this area

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can add another `stat_function()` call, specify that you want to plot the minimum of the two curves using `pmin()` and select the geom as `area`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
plot_df = data.frame(Budget = c(0, 200))
ggplot(plot_df, aes(x = Budget)) + 
  stat_function(fun = \(x) {(100 - 0.20*x)/0.70}, aes(color = "line constraint1")) + 
  stat_function(fun = \(x) {(200 - x) }, aes(color = "line constraint2")) +
  stat_function(fun = \(x) {pmin((200 - x), ((100 - 0.20*x)/0.70)) },
                geom = "area",
                fill = "blue") +
  labs(y = "Space") + 
  ggtitle("Plot kale vs Parsnips Growing")
```

which gives:

[image: area chart]